# GO - Gin/Gorm/Postgresql - Create a foreignKey with "has one" association

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I've read the documentation (https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html) and tested as suggested but I can't create the association.
My tables look like this (the names are in Italian)

```
models/tables.go

type TeatroY struct {
    gorm.Model
    Nome  string
    Posti int
}

type SpettacoloXY struct {
    gorm.Model
    Nome   string
    Teatro TeatroY `gorm:"foreignKey:id"`
}
```

and in the main I use the classic automigrate

```
initializers.DB.AutoMigrate(&models.TeatroY{}, &models.SpettacoloXY{})
```

The error I get is as follows

> "2023/04/02 16:12:24 E:/Work/Mota/cdbp4/server.go:13 ERROR: relation
> "spettacolo_xies" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01) [33.459ms] [rows:0]
> ALTER TABLE "teatro_ies" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_spettacolo_xies_teatro"
> FOREIGN KEY ("id") REFERENCES "spettacolo_xies"("id")"

After create a "TeatroY", when I create a "SpettacoloXY" the "Teatro" field must be associated with one and only one "TeatroY"

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the model migration code to this:

```golang
initializers.DB.AutoMigrate(&models.SpettacoloXY{}, &models.TeatroY{})
```

will get rid of the error and will create both tables in the database.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think about the migration order. The answer is perfectly correct. Thank you so much Aritra